# How to find elements in array that contain a given substring?

Tags: php, arrays, filter, substring

I have 3 strings, I would like to get only the equal strings of them, something like this:

```
$Var1 = "Sant";
$Array[] = "Hello Santa Claus";   // Name_1
$Array[] = "Santa Claus";         // Name_2
```

I would like to get both of them because they match **"Sant"**.

With my code I only get `Name_2`

```
$len = strlen($Var1);
foreach($Array as $name) 
{
   if (  stristr($Var1, substr($name, 0, $len)))
   {
     echo $name;
   }
}
```

I understand why I only get `Name_2`, but I don't know how to solve this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Your code will work too like below:-***

```
foreach ($Array as $name)
{
    if (stristr($name,$Var1)!==false)
    {
        echo $name;
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/812376

***You can use [php strpos() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) also for this purpose***

```
foreach($Array as $name) 
{
   if (  strpos($name,$Var1)!==false)
   {
     echo $name;
     echo PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/812371

***Note:-*** In Both function the first argument is the string in which you want to search the sub-string. And second argument is sub-string itself.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `strpos()` function of php to identify if a string consist a substring or not as

```
$a = 'Sant';
foreach($Array as $name) 
{
    if (strpos($name, $a) !== false) {
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do it like this. You can use `stristr` but you have to flip arguments because you are passing wrong arguments. First argument should be `haystack` and second should be `needle`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/812373)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$Var1 = "Sant";
$Array[] = "Hello Santa Claus";   // Name_1
$Array[] = "Santa Claus";         // Name_2


foreach ($Array as $name)
{
    if (stristr($name,$Var1)!==false)
    {
        echo $name;
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "filter" your "array", I recommend using the php function called `array_filter()` like this:

Code:

```
$Var1 = "Sant";
$Array=["Hello Santa Claus","Easter Bunny","Santa Claus"];

var_export(array_filter($Array,function($v)use($Var1){return strpos($v,$Var1)!==false;}));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Hello Santa Claus',
  2 => 'Santa Claus',
)
```

`array_filter()` needs the array as the first parameter, and the search term inside of `use()`.  The return portion tells the function to retain the element if `true` and remove the element if `false`.

The benefit to this function over a foreach loop is that no output variables needs to be declared (unless you want one).  It performs the same iterative action.

Code Update: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2pIN8))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $Array,
        fn($v) => str_contains($v, $Var1)
    )
);
```

Comment: how can I handle it ?

Comment: @PaulNoris What are you asking?  I am happy to help you if you clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I mean I want to separate on 2 variables, the number of the array and the value, because I show it on different places............ Thank you so much @mickmackusa !!

Comment: @PaulNoris Can you show me your code (pastebin.com link or http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ link)?  I can offer a more accurate response if I better understand what "show it in different places" means.  (my daughter is unwell this evening, so I may be a bit slow in responding, but I will respond)

Comment: for sure http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e361b545bffb251b4051bb834ae8cec1cd10153c

Comment: @PaulNoris How close does this get you?  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/98e9785f7dcf83ab433368f52e0df026c770ebc6  (`stripos()` is faster than `stristr()`)