# PHP Print array with specific word

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have multidimensional array

```
    array (Test1, 10)
    array (Quiz1, 5)
    array (Test2, 5)
    array (Quiz2, 10)
```

I print that array into table.

```
Test1 | Quiz1 | Test2 | Quiz2
:---- | ----: | :---- | ----:
10    | 5     | 5     | 10
```

How I want to print only show array contain word "Test"?

results

```
Test1 | Test2 | 
:---- | :---- | 
 10   | 5     |
```

My code to only sort the array:

```
$quiz_ids = et_curriculum_quizes($course_id);
       // Sort Quiz By Alphabet 
                sort($quiz_ids);
                $tlength = count($quiz_ids);
                for($x = 0; $x < $tlength; $x++);
```

Output:

```
    Test1 | Test2 | Quiz1 | Quiz2
    :---- | ----: | :---- | ----:
    10    | 5     | 5     | 10
```

This is the code for the table header:

```
 foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
 echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($quiz_id).'" target="_blank">'.get_the_title($quiz_id). ('</a></th>';
```

**UPDATE**

My code to display value

```
 <?php
      foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
                        echo '<td>'.get_post_meta($quiz_id,$member_id,true).'</td>';
                    }


                $sum=0;           
                $status = bp_course_get_user_course_status($member_id,$course_id);
                if($status > 3){
                    $marks = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id, true);
                    $sum += $marks;
                    echo '<td>'.$marks.'</td>';    
                }else{
                    echo '<td>'._x('N.A','Marks not available in batch statisitcs leaderboard','wplms-batches').'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
                $i++;
```

Output when I put var_dump
I have 8 Test and 8 Quiz

```
array(16) { 
[0]=> string(3) "570" 
[1]=> string(3) "775" 
[2]=> string(3) "779" 
[3]=> string(3) "781" 
[4]=> string(3) "783" 
[5]=> string(3) "785" 
[6]=> string(3) "787" 
[7]=> string(3) "789" 
[8]=> string(3) "818" 
[9]=> string(3) "885" 
[10]=> string(3) "887" 
[11]=> string(3) "895" 
[12]=> string(3) "911" 
[13]=> string(3) "971" 
[14]=> string(3) "985" 
[15]=> string(3) "987" }
```

Comment: Where is this array generated?  database? file? api?  Perhaps omit the unwanted subarrays beforehand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements in array that contain a given substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382283/how-to-find-elements-in-array-that-contain-a-given-substring)

Comment: `This Code For Table Header` =>ok and what about values?

Comment: @AlivetoDie Why did you delete your answer?  While _I_ believe this is a duplicate question, your answer showed better practice than Andreas'.  If this question is not closed, future readers should be learning from your method.

Comment: @mickmackusa  because i am unable to incorporate my answer code in OP's given code. So if  me itself unable to do that. I don't think OP can do that.

Comment: This question has become a dog's breakfast.  Please provide a complete, minimal, coherent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your foreach you can match value with "Test" using Substr.
Substr will take only the start of the word so a value like "QuizTest" will not return true.

```
Foreach($quiz_ids as $subarray){
    If(Substr($subarray[0], 0,4) == "Test") echo  $subarray[0] . " " . $subarray[1];
}
```